# change the ios developer name for specific apps

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have the developer account which use my name to apply (Individual Account). 
Now , I'm making the apps for the school group project and I want to upload(publish) it with the group name . I don't want to correct my account's name because i have another apps uploaded before.

can I just correct the developer name of one apps?

Comment: If it's linked to your developer account it will show the name from your account. If you want a different name to appear you'd need to create a new developer account.

Answer (score 0):

If your group has it's own developer account in AppStore, it's possible to transfer the app from your account to group's account.

Comment: that means i cannot have 2 names in one account ?